# How to override default Grails environment?

Tags: grails, environment-variables, overriding

Grails allows you to define different "environments" for your app inside `Config.groovy` like so:

```
environments {
    development {
        ...
    }
    demo {
        ...
    }
    production {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thus you can run your app like so:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=demo run-app
```

...and Grails will run your app in "demo" environment mode. The default is `development`, so if you just execute:

```
grails run-app
```

...it's the same as:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=development run-app
```

However I was wondering if it is possible (and if so, how) to override `development` as the default and make it, say, `demo`? Such that:

```
grails run-app
```

...is equivalent to:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=demo run-app
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> However I was wondering if it is possible (and if so, how) to override development as the default

No, this is not possible. Incidentally, the default environment depends on the command, e.g.

- the default environment for `run-app` is `development`
- the default environment for `test-app` is `test`
- the default environment for `war` is `production`

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no (or at least it is not documented and I wasn't able to make it work), but the slightly longer answer is that even if you could you probably don't want to.

By changing the default environment you'll create an additional barrier to entry for new developers and are likely to have quite a few "oh damn, it doesn't run in dev by default, of course" moments.

It's also worth noting that while the `development` is the default for `run-app`, `test-app` defaults to `test` and `war` defaults to `production`.

The `development` environment is just a label, so if you really wanted to use it for something else (such as demos), you could just create a separate `actualDev` environment, but again it's likely to cause confusion in the distant future when everyone's forgotten it's set up like that.

#### Okay, but what can I do to make demos easier?

I've always made use of the `/scripts/` directory in the standard Grails structure to ease setup and demo overheads, so you could create `demo.sh` for demos, which would also let you setup/teardown any other resources if/when your application becomes more complex and interconnected.